# Problem filtering in decimal datatype in Sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to fetch all the records that have null in openingbalance field of my voucher table in sql server 2005 database. That field is of type decimal(18,0).
My query is

```
Select HeadCode,HeadName
from VoucherHead
where OpeniningBalanace = null
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check for null using `IS`, rather than `=`

```
Select HeadCode,HeadName
from VoucherHead
where OpeniningBalanace IS null
```

Answer (score 1):

Hence the little difference:

```
Select HeadCode,HeadName
from VoucherHead
where OpeniningBalanace IS NULL
```